# Customize Create Method option in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ide, jetbrains-ide

When I write code to call a method that not exist yet, Android Studio makes it red and when i press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> it suggeests to Create method $NAME$.

How can I customize this template of method creation?

Comment: with customization you mean changing the shortcuts which trigger this macro ? Or do you want to change how the method $NAME$ is created ?

Comment: i want to change how the method $NAME$ is created. Exactly i want to throw exception in it by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found how to do it in `File` -> `Settings` -> `File and Code Templates` -> `Code` tab -> `New Method Body`